# Return attribute values from object for list of attributes

Tags: python, class, attributes

Suppose I have some class:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a=1, b=2, c=3):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
```

I want to be able to access multiple attributes from an instance of this class by passing an iterable of attribute names to some function:

```
def access_attr(attrs, obj=A()):
    return {a: eval('obj.{}'.format(a)) for a in attrs}

access_attr(attrs=['a', 'b'])
# returns {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

I don't know whether using `eval` is the best way of doing this? Is there a canonical way to accomplish this task?

Comment: It definitely isn't. Use `getattr()`.

Comment: Ah. I was familiar with `hasattr` -- should've known there was a `getattr`!